# Source Control System Setup

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am looking for a good source control system. I would like to use git but I need something with a good user interface. I know Tortoise SVN has a nice user interface. Are there any others like tortoise SVN that has a nice user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly suggest GIT over SVN as GIT is better for collaboration and its also better when merging changes.

There is a nice tutorial here on how to setup a git server:
http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux

its pretty simple

It can be setup on any OS.

Mike

Comment: I need the GUI that tortoise provides otherwise yes I agree Git is much better.

Comment: have you checked out github?  An amazing gui that wraps git.  The only caveat is that your code must be hosted as open source, you can however pay a nominal fee to privatize your repositories.  It is totally worth it for git in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

I use tortoise myself and it is really good, it just had a new update which made the commit manager a lot easier and smoother to use. Definitely recommend tortoiseSVN for large groups and git for smaller groups.